# CodeIgniter Rest Server Library - Session in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using [Codeigniter REST_Controller](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) library to create a webservice server.

I use native Codeigniter sessions and sessions table to store my sessions. I noticed that all calls made on my server via webservices are stored in the session table. Is there a way to not register base open sessions via webservices?

Answer (score 0):

Go to :

```
application/config/config.php
```

Change

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

By

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
```

Now your session is stored locally.
I hope it will help you.

Comment: I agree but I want to continue to store my sessions in my database for my real users.